# TortoiseSVN Can't Authenticate

Tags: apache, svn, authentication, tortoisesvn, sasl

After my previous problem, [TortoiseSVN Can't Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820835/tortoisesvn-cant-connect) was resolved, I ran into a new problem.
On the linux server hosting my svn repository, in the repository's directory, there is a `conf/svnserve.conf` file. In this file, I have the option:

```
anon-access = none | read | write
```

Initially, this line was commented out and the default value must have been `read`.
Of course, I want to set `anon-access = none`, and I want `auth-access = write` (which is the default).

But when I set `anon-access = none`, when I try to browse with **TortoiseSVN Repository Browser**
using url `svn://host:port/repositoryname`, I get the error:

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'svn://host:port/repositoryname' No access allowed to this repository

I'd like to successfully authenticate without ssh if possible, because I gather ssh has more moving parts and might be a little slower.

The server is **CloudLinux Server release 5.8**

The svn server information follows. I have only tried svn protocol so far.

> svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)    compiled Jul 26 2012, 03:59:19
>
> Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet. Subversion is open source software,
>   see http://subversion.apache.org/ This product includes software
>   developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).
>
> The following repository access (RA) modules are available:
>
> - ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
>
>   - handles 'http' scheme
> - ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
>
>   - with Cyrus SASL authentication
>   - handles 'svn' scheme
> - ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
>
>   - handles 'file' scheme
> - ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
>
>   - handles 'http' scheme
>   - handles 'https' scheme

I hope this is a good question because this is kind of the "out of the box" behavior connecting to svn with windows, which might be pretty common when someone adds svn to a shared hosting account.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set these lines in your svnserve.conf file:

```
 19 anon-access = none
 20 auth-access = write
    [...]
 27 password-db = passwd
    [...]
 39 realm = Name-of-your-repository
 46 force-username-case = lower
```

The line numbers are approximate.

The `realm` should equal the name of your repository. It can be anything. The `password-db` is who is authorized to use the repository. By default, the line is NOPed out.

Next, you'll edit the `passwd` file that's in the same directory. The format is very simple:

```
 <userName> = <password>
```

There are two NOPed entries that show you how it's done.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I didn't find a `force-username-case` line, but that didn't affect the outcome. At that point, when I went into **TortoiseSVN Repository Browser**, it prompted me for authentication and had a checkbox to save the login information so I wouldn't have to keep repeating the login. **VisualSVN** inside **Visual Studio 2010** works as well. This was simple but for some reason hard for me to find.